# WPF updating parameterized bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a property in a class:

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property GetLiteral(Key As String) As String
    Get
        Try
            Dim Row() As String = _LookupTable.Item(Key)
            Return Row(_CurrentLanguage)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ("Error")
        End Try
    End Get
End Property
```

And I bind a label to it:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SLP.[LITERAL_USERNAME]}"/>
```

Where SLP is a public property in my view model containing an instance of the class containing the default property GetLiteral.

The above binding works fine.  I can select different languages in my view.  However, I wish to also be able to change languages on the fly, and I can't figure out how to raise INotifyPropertyChanged in order to make this binding update.  I know I could probably achieve this easily with a value converter and parameter, but I like the simplicity of the XAML above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was calling NotifyPropertyChanged from inside SLP, where what I really needed to do was call NotifyPropertyChanged(Me, "SLP") from the View Model.